# How do I unit test UI via console

Tags: unit-testing, browser, user-interface, web

I know this has been asked many times but I want to be specific.
I use to use selenium. After googling it looks like I can run it via console and it gives me a bunch of text output but I rather not parse that and I want a pass/fail type of thing

Every once in a while I like to run all of my unit test on the UI not code. I don't want to submit a form with certain values, I want to see if I click this img does the dropbox beside it pop out and if i select a name will it be in the form which I'll then submit after running a few other things.

The reason I'd like this is certain features MUST ALWAYS be working so i'm ok with adjusting the unit test everytime I modify the UI for those feature. For the rest the unit test in code which checks business logic will be enough as those UIs are always changing or not very important.

It be nice if something can kickoff firefox and chrome (or webkit) but thats not required.

Like I said I'd like pass/fail, some kind of easy text to parse. Complex test is ok as I know regex but I don't want to figure out when one unit test ends or starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using java/maven - I wrote a maven plugin for selenium that should do what you want:

https://github.com/willwarren/selenium-maven-plugin.  You generate the tests in firefox + selenium, then save the files to a directory in your maven project.

If you're not using maven you can use the project that I built upon:

http://code.google.com/p/selenium4j

From the Readme:

We use selenium IDE to record our tests. We then saved the test cases into our project in the following fashion: (Note: currently the code from selenium4j only suports one level, so don't nest your folders)

```
./src/test/selenium
    |-signin
        |-LoginGoodPassword.html
        |-LoginBadPassword.html
        |-selenium4j.properties
```

We didn't save the test suites as maven takes care of finding your tests.

The selenium4j.properties contains setup information about:

```
# the web site being tested
webSite=http://yourwebapp:8080

# A comma separated values of the WebDrivers being used. Accepted drivers: 
# HtmlUnitDriver, FirefoxDriver, ChromeDriver, InternetExplorerDriver
driver=FirefoxDriver

# How many times we want to iterate and test
loopCount=1
```

The selenium maven plugin, which is bound to the process-test-resources phase, then converts these html files into junit 4 tests in your src/test/java folder.

So you end up with:

```
./src/test/java
    |-signin
        |-firefox
            |-LoginGoodPasswordTest.java
            |-LoginBadPasswordTest.java
```